# what TERM to use to get rid of color escape codes?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Is there a way to get rid of escape codes in terminal output?

Say even if the script are sending that codes they are ignored by terminal and text displayed as is, without colors, bolds etc.

I need to display terminal output on a HTML page.

For now i'm using javascript to remove escape codes, but it becomes clunky cause i receive output by chars, and have to wait until all content received then update it, leading in weird effects.

Answer (score 1):

A program can output anything on STDOUT, including escape codes, regardless of the value of TERM.  However, setting TERM to 'dumb' will help with most programs which check the terminal capabilities for color support.

Also, some programs check that STDOUT is pointing at an interactive terminal and not a pipe or file before formatting their output.   These programs can be redirected to a file, or piped through something else, such as `cat` or `less -r`.

If you narrow the problem down to a subset of escapes, those which change colors and not cursor position, you should be able to check for ESC, set a flag to stop echoing characters onto the page and clear the flag after an 'm'.